# Determining if one user follows another using the Instagram API

Tags: instagram

I'm a fairly beginner programmer trying my hand with the Instagram API. I have everything set up, and the app I'm building requires one to see if one user follows another or not. Is there a way to check this one statement rather than getting a whole list of a user's followers? Much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the logged-in user's relationship with any other user with API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

you can check the `incomming_status` and `outgoing_status` in the response.

There is no API is check relationship between random 2 users directly.

Comment: Due to the new privacy policies from Instagram, it is marked now as deprecated to get the relationship between the user and the own Instagram page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/